# Why does my PC crash when opening game menus?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, crash

My PC has a tendency to crash when I open some game menus (like inventory or map). Specifically, it happens in both AC: Origins and Genshin Impact.

The crash in and of itself is quite unusual. It's not the games crashing, nor is it windows. Instead, the screen turns black and then the entire PC starts up as if it had been off and I had just turned it on.

These crashes are always preceeded by either opening an in-game menu or (rarely) starting a game). However, they do not always happen when taking those actions. As a matter of fact, I have seldomly observed it more than once per day, even when playing for hours.

The really strange thing is that I already had this bug well over a year ago. It stopped after some time and I credited it to the driver update I had done at that point. But now my drivers are up to date and it still happens.

My specs:

- OS: Windows 10
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- Mainboard: B450M-A PRO MAX
- Memory: 16GB DDR4
- GPU: AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT

Comment: "Instead, the screen turns black and then it starts up as if it had been off and I had just turned it on." - This means the display driver is crashing.  Windows has been able to recover from this type of error since Windows Vista. I assume by "in-game menu" you are talking about the Steam in-game overlay?  If it's not Steam's overlay you should specify which one it is.

Comment: In how far is Windows able to recover from this error? The entire PC goes down immediately, without a bluescreen and just powers up again. What about that is recovery?

Comment: No, I do not mean the steam overlay but the, well, the menu. The one that appears when you press ESC. Although map or inventory can also do it. As far as I can tell it is everything that causes the (3D) rendered scene not to be displayed anymore, but that is a bit of a guess.

Comment: No, I meant the PC starts up, not windows or the screen. I see a black screen and then the PC powers up as if I had shut it down, mainboard logo and all. There is no BSOD, its as if I had cut the power and then turned it back on.

Comment: Before the change was introduced into the Windows NT kernel, a display driver crash, would bring the entire system with it.  As you point out, Windows is recovering from this error, or that's how I took "the screen turns black and then it starts up as if it had been off and I had just turned it on".  If a BSOD is being created, then use WinDBG on it, to analyze the .dmp file.  Without the WinDBG analysis output there isn't much to diagnose.

Comment: So not .dmp file is being created?  Have you considered the problem is your GPU?

Comment: There are no .dmp-files in C:\Windows\Minidump. I'm not certain how I would consider my GPU. Sure, the hardware might be faulty, but is there a way I could validate that? Some benchmark or memory checker?

Comment: To me this sounds like it could be a power supply issue.  I would check the 12v rail and make sure it stays at 12v.  Using software to monitor your 12v rail, download, install, and run Furmark and see if your PC crashes or the voltage dips to 11.4v or less.  It could also be insufficient ventilation.

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer if you can find relevant messages.

Comment: I am glad you said that @cybernard .. I was thinking the same thing.  It was also an important feature he left out of the posted specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in the AMD Support Forum. Apparently the culprit is the AMD External Events Utility. I simply disabled the service and have had no problem since.

https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/7900-xt-pc-crashing-when-games-are-in-full-screen-or-borderless/m-p/610526/highlight/true#M175901